# Schubert Cell Structure for some variety with prescribed bilinear form

Tags: bilinear-form, cw-complexes, schubert-calculus

We know the construction of Schubert cell complex structure for the case of Grassmann manifold $Gr_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ i.e variety of all k- dimensional subspaces $V$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Consider that there is bilinear form B on $\mathbb{C}^n$. How to give a Schubert cell structure on the set of all V, k- dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that B restricted on V is nonsingular.

Thank you in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean nondegenerate?

Comment: @MattSamuel: Yes. I mean nondegenerate.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Dear Sir, what happened to the answer? Is there any problem with that answer? I guess that was fine.

Comment: I wasn't confident it was correct. If you want I can undelete it